# How to add Ionic2 native button click sound?

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, npm, ionic2

Many native app's buttons have a native click sound. Can anyone please tell me how to add native click sound for all buttons in Ionic 2.

Comment: [Native Click Sound Cordova Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativeclicksound "Native Click Sound Cordova Plugin") by [@matimenich](https://www.npmjs.com/~matimenich) does just that (Android and iOS) - but **I am also struggling to make it work in Ionic 2** (all the docs/examples are for older ionic/angular). So this is not really a complete answer, more a pointer in (hopefully) a good direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Nativeclick plugin in Ionic 2:

**Install the plugin:**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativeclicksound
```

**Add necessary imports:**

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
```

**Declare a variable before `@Component` decorator:**

```
declare var nativeclick;
```

That way, TypeScript would not complain about 'nativeclick' not being defined.

**In constructor, use the following code:**

```
constructor(private platform: Platform) {

this.platform.ready().then( (val) => {
    if (val === 'cordova'){
      var clickyClasses = ['button', 'a']; // add other classes that should make a sound when clicked on
      nativeclick.watch(clickyClasses);
    }
});
```

If you don't use the platform check ( `==='cordova'` ), your code will break when used in browser.

If anyone could point out names of some other classes we could use (e.g. radio-buttons, list items, back buttons on navigations etc.), I would be grateful.

Comment: One word I want to say that "WOW" for this.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Why dont use in try catch block instead of check platform

Comment: I guess it could also be done in `try...catch` block. I prefer this method, since in real life there are usually more things to do/initialize depending on platform, and in my opinion this is more readable code. Anyway, this check is only done once per app start, so there is really no performance impact in using either. It comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Note that the `nativeclick.watch` function only takes **classes** (and not tag names as somewhat suggested by the code given in this answer).

Answer (score 1):

Although this question asks specifically about Ionic 2, [it's currently still the top Google result](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=ionic+3+nativeclick) even when searching about Ionic 3.

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45454268/4877269) doesn't work for Ionic 3; Ionic 3 components are probably assigned different class names to Ionic 2 components.

The solution below works for Ionic 3 (and might also work for Ionic 2).  It registers a document-wide event handler to inspect the clicked element and its ancestors, and manually triggers `nativeclick` if a `<button>` is found:

```
// ↓↓↓ BEGIN ADDITION 1 OF 2 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

declare var nativeclick: { trigger: () => void };

// ↑↑↑ END ADDITION /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// @Component({ templateUrl: 'app.html' })
// class MyApp

constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

// ↓↓↓ BEGIN ADDITION 2 OF 2 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        const nativeClickListener = (event: Event) => {
            // Traverse through the clicked element and all ancestors.
            for (
                let curElement = <Element> event.target;
                curElement != null;
                curElement = curElement.parentElement
            ) {
                // If a BUTTON element is encountered, trigger a click and stop.
                if (curElement.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
                  // ‘nativeclick’ doesn't exist outside Cordova's environment.
                  typeof nativeclick !== 'undefined' && nativeclick.trigger();
                  break;
                }
            }
        };
        // Call the above listener whenever anything is clicked, ensuring that it
        // is called before more specific EventTargets (or else clicks won't be
        // heard on e.g. <ion-datetime> components or <ion-navbar> back buttons).
        document.addEventListener('click', nativeClickListener, true);

// ↑↑↑ END ADDITION /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        statusBar.styleDefault();
        splashScreen.hide();
    });
}
```

The above code assumes that you've installed the `cordova-plugin-nativeclicksound` plugin:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativeclicksound
```

Although looking for only `<button>` elements has been enough for me, it might be necessary to watch for more tag names.  Adjust as necessary.